# The I got this error "method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, int)"

Tags: java

I got this error:

> "method format(String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments   (String, int, int, int)"

The following is the code, please anyone can help me!

```
//Time1 class declaration maintains the time in 24-hour format.
public class Time1 {
    private int hour; // 0-23
    private int minute; //0-59
    private int second; //0-59

    //set a new time value using universal time; throw 
    //an exception if the hour, minute or second
    //is invalid.
    public void setTime(int hour, int minute, int second) {
        //validate hour, minute and second
        if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24 || minute < 0 || minute >= 60 || second < 0 || second >= 60) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour, minute and/or second was out of range");
        }

        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }

    //convert to String in universal-time format (HH:MM:SS)
    public String toUniversalString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
    }

    //convert to String in standard-time format(H:MM:SS AM or PM)
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s", ((hour == 0 || hour == 12) ? 12 : hour % 12),
        minute, second, (hour < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));
    }
} // end class Time1
```

Comment: Are you compiling this at Java compiler level 1.5 or higher?

Comment: Guys, he has a legitimate question. Stop the down-votes. @HotLicks: the error message does not make sense. He may be compiling the code at level Java 1.4. His code **should** work.

Comment: Furthermore, when manipulating dates and time, your should use `DateFormat`, and optionally (but advised) JodaTime. This way you can validate your data in a much nicer way

Comment: @HotLicks I thought so too, at first, but on closer reading I agree with Hovercraft. Pretty much any tutorial you'll find these days would indicate that this code should compile; you need to be decently versed in (fairly ancient, at this point) Java history to know why it doesn't.

Comment: the error message marked as red x and shows beside the code

Comment: @HotLicks So why doesn't it auto box the `int` values.  It does in later version of Java.

Comment: @HotLicks `String.format` is a vararg method. There is tons of code that does not explicitly pass an `Object[]` as the last argument; I've written probably half a dozen such lines this afternoon alone. It's reasonable to see that code (from an example, a tutorial, etc) and wonder why this error messages is coming up.

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @user3618186 most like the problem is your version of Java.  Which version and which update are you using?

Comment: user3618186, what version of javac are you using? What's the output of `javac -version`, if you're compiling from command line? And if you're using an IDE, do you know what version of javac it's using?

Comment: I've been asking him repeatedly to tell me how he's compiling this, what version of Java, but he's ignoring the request.

Comment: eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2 and jre8

Comment: @user3618186: you must check the Java compliance level that Eclipse is using. Likely it's 1.4. Right click on your project, then click on properties, then java compiler.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Just out curiosity, this issue is due to a failure to wrap, is it not?

Comment: Yes. There are two things that need to happen in Java 1.5+ for this code to work: (a) the `int`s need to be autoboxed to `Integer` and (b) the "trailing" arguments (after the first `String` arg) need to be wrapped into an `Object[]`.

Comment: The java compliance level is 1.4

Comment: @christopher: the issue is due to failure to compile with Java 1.5 or higher. Autoboxing is not occurring.

Comment: @user3618186: make the compliance level 1.7 or 1.8.

Comment: user3618186, bump it up to at least 1.5 for this code to work; the features required (in my comment right before this last one) were introduced in Java 5. You may want to bump it up to 1.7 (or even 1.8, if you're feeling adventurous and kepler supports it!).

Comment: Alternately, SEARCH BEFORE ASKING. Because there's a question with almost exactly the same title. And it's answered with a workaround for 1.4.

Comment: I changed java compliance level to 1.7. Now the red x disappears. Thank you guys! NO error now!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Can you post your comments as an answer?